# Update stored procedure in edmx file

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have updated stored procedure by deleting column and added `where` clause. The stored procedure already added in the edmx file. Now I want to update those changes in edmx file. I tried by deleting stored procedure and update model from database. How do I update edmx file with updated stored procedure?

Comment: Didn't you already do it by "_deleting stored procedure and update model from database_"? Did that not work? Did something go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to delete from the `Complex Types`. After deleting from it, it worked.